# mySQL password not working when installing Phabricator

Tags: mysql, phabricator, ubuntu-18.04

I seem to be unable to set a valid MySQL root password that Phabricator can use during the installation.

Every time I try to restart the phd daemons (as per these instructions: https://gist.github.com/sparrc/b4eff48a3e7af8411fc1) I get the following exception:

```
[2018-09-20 08:38:09] EXCEPTION: (PhabricatorClusterStrandedException) Unable to establish a connection to any database host (while trying "phabricator_config"). All masters and replicas are completely unreachable.

AphrontConnectionQueryException: Attempt to connect to root@127.0.0.1 failed with error #1698: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/lisk/PhabricatorLiskDAO.php:158]
```

I was, however, able to successfully complete the `./bin/storage upgrade` Phabricator command after reinstalling MySQL.

I have tried:

- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7` - Didn't prompt for a new password
- Logging in with `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` and running update commands on the root password. All seems to be successful, but as soon as I try Phabricator again, I get the exception.
- Looking for temporary passwords:

  > sudo grep "temporary password" /var/log/mysqld.log
  >   grep: /var/log/mysqld.log: No such file or directory

Note that I am using `./bin/config set mysql.pass 'mypassword'` after changing it using any of the methods above. I've tried no password as well, which doesn't work. Once I have run the Phabricator storage upgrade command, I can no longer access mySQL at all and any steps to reset passwords seem to take no effect.

I'm running MySQL 5.7 and PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 18.04